# Работа с множествами в Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, множества

Всем привет, у меня очередной глупый вопрос, возникший в процессе изучения Джанго.

Задача: на сайте сделать блок, куда будут выводиться все тэги всех статей.

в views.py пока что руками задаю данные:

```
news = [
    {
        'title': 'Первая запись',
        'text': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        'date': '13.03.1934',
        'autor': 'admin',
        'main_img': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c846021/v846021439/113f5a/8Vx_3mfKpfU.jpg',
        'tags': ['статья', 'первая']
    },
    {
        'title': 'Первая запись',
        'text': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        'date': '13.03.1934',
        'autor': 'admin',
        'main_img': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c846021/v846021439/113f5a/8Vx_3mfKpfU.jpg',
        'tags': ['статья', 'первая', 'копия']

    },
    {
        'title': 'Вторая запись',
        'text': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        'date': '13.03.1966',
        'autor': 'admin',
        'main_img': 'https://pp.userapi.com/c846021/v846021439/113f5a/8Vx_3mfKpfU.jpg',
        'tags': ['статья', 'вторая']



        }
]
```

И есть вот такой код:

```
def index(request):
data = {
    'news': news,
    'title': 'Тайтл'
}

all_hashtags = set([])

for post in news:
    set.update(all_hashtags, post['tags'])
    return all_hashtags

return render(request, 'blog/index.html', data, all_hashtags)
```

При попытке выполнения вылезает ошибка:

```
   Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 2.1.4
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog.apps.BlogConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  93.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py" in process_response
  26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Подскажите, где ошибка? Я что-то не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите сигнатуру метода `render` в модуле `django.shortcuts`:

```
def render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None):
...
```

4-ый аргумент - content_type, а вы туда явно не то кладёте. Рискну предположить, что вам нужно ваши `all_hashtags` передавать под дополнительным ключом в `data`.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно затупил. После передачи множества в data все заработало.